# Frequency of a variable by month

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I am looking for colour frequency by month. I would like to make a line graph with each colour's percentage for each month. This is my data:

```
ID    color1   color2  color3  date
55    red     blue     NA     2020-03-15
67    yellow  NA       NA     2020-05-02
83    blue    yellow   NA     2020-05-17
78    red     yellow   blue   2020-05-15  
43    green   NA       NA     2021-01-27
29    yellow  green    NA     2021-01-03
```

I need something like this to graph. I need the month's article count as the denominator. So if the `ID` has multiple colours (for example, all `IDs` in `03/2020` are blue and red), the total percentage can be higher than 100.

```
Month     n  freq_blue freq_red  freq_yellow  freq_green %_blue %_red   _yellow %_green
03-2020   1    1        1          0           0            100  100     0       0
04-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
05-2020   3    2        1          3           0            66.7  33.3   100     0
06-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
07-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
08-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
09-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
10-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
11-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
12-2020   0    0        0          0           0            0     0      0       0
01-2021   2    0        0          1           2            0     0      50     100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some code would help make it clearer what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: df$date <-as.Date(df$date)
df2<- df %>%
  mutate(month = month(date), year = year(date)) 
df2 <-covid_totals_filtered %>%
  group_by(month,year) %>%
  mutate(count=length(unique(PMID)))
df2<- df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("color")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(month, year, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(year, month = 1:12, value = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green"), fill = list(n = 0, 
percent = 0)) %>%

Comment: pivot_wider(id_cols = c(month, year), names_from = value, values_from = c(n, percent))

Comment: Thats what I have tried so far, too many characters to fit in one line, sorry

Comment: You can [edit] the question to include your code, where it will be much, much easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, it is helpful if you could edit your original post/question with your code instead of in the comments below.

Based on what you have (and your prior question) this may be helpful.

Consider creating a new column `month_total` that you can use for percentage calculation - it appears you want to know the number of IDs for a given month (it was unclear if a color could appear more than once in a row).

After you determine the frequencies and percentages, and use `complete` to fill in missing months and colors, you can use `fill` to include the monthly totals as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>%
  mutate(month = month(date), year = year(date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("color")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  mutate(month_total = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  group_by(value, month_total, .add = T) %>%
  summarise(freq = n(), percent = freq/month_total[1] * 100) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(year, month = 1:12, value = c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green"), fill = list(freq = 0, percent = 0)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  fill(month_total, .direction = "updown") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(month, year, month_total), names_from = value, values_from = c(freq, percent)) %>%
  replace_na(list(month_total = 0))
```

**Output**

```
   month  year month_total freq_blue freq_green freq_red freq_yellow percent_blue percent_green percent_red percent_yellow
   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 2     2  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 3     3  2020           1         1          0        1           0        100               0       100                0
 4     4  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 5     5  2020           3         2          0        1           3         66.7             0        33.3            100
 6     6  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 7     7  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 8     8  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
 9     9  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
10    10  2020           0         0          0        0           0          0               0         0                0
# … with 14 more rows
```